# KDB: how do I do bulk insert in Java?

Tags: kdb

I have a table with String columns "key1", "col1", "col2", "col3". I have a snippet below to test the bulk insert. When I run it, I don't get any error, yet I don't see any changes to the "test" table.

Did I miss something?

```
        Object[][] data = new Object[4][];

        ArrayList<String>[] rec = new ArrayList[4];

        rec[0] = new ArrayList<String>();  
        rec[1] = new ArrayList<String>();  
        rec[2] = new ArrayList<String>();  
        rec[3] = new ArrayList<String>(); 

        for (Integer i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

            rec[0].add(i.toString() + i.toString() + i.toString());
            rec[1].add(i.toString() + i.toString() + i.toString());
            rec[2].add(i.toString() + i.toString() + i.toString());
            rec[3].add(i.toString() + i.toString() + i.toString());

        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            data[i] = rec[i].toArray(new Object[rec[i].size()]);
        }

        c.Dict dict = new c.Dict(Arrays.asList("key1", "col1", "col2", "col3").toArray(new String[4]), data);
        c.Flip flip = new c.Flip(dict);

        Object[] updStatement = new Object[] { ".u.upd", "test", flip };

        conn.ks(updStatement);
```

Comment: create a local q session, put the same test schema there, update the operation from .u.upd to insert and test it. you will see the error on the console if anything is wrong with the schema or the data you are sending.

Comment: there was an error. it says 'insert

Comment: Apparently this does not work for me: Object[] updStatement = new Object[] { "insert", "test", flip }; conn.ks(updStatement);. What worked is this: conn.ks("insert", "test", flip);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding onto what you said, you want to be using the [ks() method with 2 arguments](https://code.kx.com/q/interfaces/java-client-for-q/#sending-syncasync-messages).

From the javadoc given in the [c.java class](https://github.com/KxSystems/javakdb/blob/master/src/kx/c.java):

> Use this to
>      * invoke a function in kdb+ which takes 2 arguments and does not return a value. e.g. to invoke f[x;y] use ks("f",x,y);
>      * to invoke a lambda, use ks("{x+y}",x,y);

The function `.u.upd` takes in 2 arguments and, by default, has the same signature as [insert](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/qsql/#insert):

- First argument is a symbol for the table name, which has the type String in Java
- Second argument is the records which has the type Object[] in Java

The length of the Object[] in the second argument should be equal to the number of columns. Each Object in the Object[] should itself be an array that has a length equal to the number of records. The order of the inner arrays should be the same order as the columns, and the values of each inner array should have the [matching type](https://code.kx.com/q/interfaces/java-client-for-q/#type-mapping) to the column type in kdb and have the same order as the records.

Your Object[] should look like:

```
new Object[]{
    new Object[]{row1col1, row2col1, /*..., */ rowNcol1},
    new Object[]{row1col2, row2col2, /*..., */ rowNcol2},
    /* column 3 to column N-1 values */
    new Object[]{row1colN, row2colN, /*..., */ rowNcolN}
}
```

And your `ks()` method call should look like:

```
conn.ks(".u.upd", "test", new Object[]{ /*.... */});
```